# Capistrano 3: incompatible ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am deploying a rails app to Ubuntu 14.04 using Capistrano.

In remote Ubuntu server it shows I am using Ruby 2.3.0
I tried these commands to install Ruby

rbenv install 2.3.0 
rbenv global 2.3.0
rbenv rehash

```
deploy@ubuntu:~$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.3.0 (set by /home/deploy/.rbenv/version)

deploy@ubuntu:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
```

But when I try `cap production deploy`, error happens and shows a different Ruby is working, instead of 2.3.0

> activesupport-5.0.0.1 requires ruby version >= 2.2.2, which is
>   incompatible with
>
> the current version, ruby 1.9.3p484

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the result of `which cap`? It might be that the `cap` command is resolving to the system Ruby, and ignoring your Rbenv paths

Comment: In which file did you put `rbenv init` `.bashrc`?